# MSBuild, add more than one property in a build.msbuild file

Tags: cpu-architecture, msbuild-task

Please see the configuration below:

> ```
> <Target Name="CompileToTest64bit">
>   <Message Text=" *** Compiling..." />
>   <CallTarget Targets="UpdateAssemblyInfos" />
>   <MSBuild Projects="MySolution.sln" Properties="Configuration=Debug, PlatformTarget=x64"/>
> </Target>
> ```

I am trying to figure out how to add both the Configuration and the PlatformTarget property together.

I have tried:

> ```
> Properties="Configuration=Debug, PlatformTarget=x64"
> Properties="Configuration=Debug" Properties="PlatformTarget=x64"
> ```

-and a few other combinations, but nothing works :-(

Any idea how to do that?

Thank you in advanced.

/Peter

**UPDATE**

I use this configuration on a Jenkins BuildServer and the funny thing is that it seems to ignore whatever I write in Properties, except for the Configuration=Debug|Release param.

My command line argument looks like this:

> ```
> /Target:Build /p:version=%VERSION% /p:FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5"
> ```

-and I have found that adding

> ```
> /p:PlatformTarget=x64
> ```

-does work (but still ignore the target settings).

So, the way I will solve this is to create two builds in Jenkins - one building 64bit and the other one building 32bit. Not the preferred way, but useful when all other fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use `;` as the delimiter, for example:

```
<MSBuild Projects=”a1.sln…” Properties=”Configuration=Release; Architecture=x86” />
```

(Taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2007/07/17/properties-and-additionalproperties-metadata-for-items-used-in-msbuild-task-s.aspx).)

Comment: Thanks, but it is still compiling to "Any CPU" - I have tried to remove the Configuration part, just see if that would work, but no...

Comment: Did you try: ` <MSBuild Projects="MySolution.sln" Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64;PlatFormTarget=x64"/>`?

Comment: Have tried PlatformTarget, but still no luck - please see edited question.